# Cut text on left side inside button while centering

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to have a button with a text (f.e. "add to basket") which is fluid in width. If the button width is too little to show "add to basket" it must cut to "basket" only.
I did achieve most of it by splitting

```
<span class="text">add to basket</span>
```

into two parts and reverse order them in dom

```
<span class="text">basket</span><span class="text text-prefix">add to&nbsp;</span>
```

and then show them in the correct order by adding

```
.text{
   float: right;
}
```

However, the text inside the button must also be centered, which does not work so far.

Here is my fiddle, I'd appreciate any ideas: https://jsfiddle.net/5cavrrhc/

Under all circumstances, I want to avoid using JS for this.

**Solution**

Ok, here we go: https://jsfiddle.net/6etabchg/4/

Comment: Is the button repurposed on multiple pages? And are those pages different from one another? I want to know whether there is one breakpoint where the button has to change or multiple. Else media queries might be the answer.

Comment: the button is on multiple pages and can be in different sizes on one page. Media queries don't allow for elements, only viewport, so...

Comment: Are the button sizes fixed or dynamic?

Comment: @VilleKoo OP says fluid so that means dynamic. @ Raphael Jeger: I'm pretty confident in my CSS knowledge, but I don't think this is possible without some JS. There is a [js plugin called Element Queries](http://elementqueries.com/) that might work if your not that confident in your own JS skills.

Comment: @PaulvandenDool I could do it with JS, thanks. However, please look at my update above, that works without JS. I don't want to use JS for performance-reasons when it has to do with rendering.

Comment: Great solution, I'm impressed. Please add that as accepted answer later.

Comment: I'm hesitant to use my own solution as the accepted answer... is that ok with the rules here?

Comment: Yes this is actually expected if you figure out the answer before anyone else does! : )

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my co-worker and I found a solution that works nicely.

1. make the button `position: relative`
2. make the wrapper `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap-reverse; justify-content: center;` to reverse the order
3. make both inner spans `display: inline-block;flex-shrink: 0;`
4. make the one span that should remain `order: 2`

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6etabchg/8/

In addition to what we asked above, we needed a symbol before the text, shown as a square red in the example.